# Kernel panic on MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), and also with Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)

Tags: ubuntu, grub, macbook-pro, kernel-panic, ubuntu-15.04

I had a kernel panic on my MacBook Pro, which led me to erase everything from it, and install Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit) on it, from the mini iso, with the choice of erasing everything on the hard drive. And now I have this message screen which I don’t understand at all:

[image]

I fact, when I boot, I have a white screen, then GRUB screen shows up, I choose Ubuntu, and then I either have the kernel panic, GRUB screen again, or a black screen.

What should I do? Shall I enter in grub with a 'c' and do something in it ?

**Edit.** Image from the kernel panic under OS X :

[image]

As the quality is not optimal, the first line says :

`panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800fac0531): "unable to find driver for this platform : \"ACPI\".\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/iokit/Kernel/IOPlatformExpertCpp:1541`

Comment: Do you have any images of **kernel panic** when you had **OS X**?

Comment: @RACING121 I do have pictures from the kernel panic happened while I was under mac OS X. I will put them in a an edit of the question

Comment: @JakeGould Actually I've installed ubuntu 15.04 64bits from mini iso on a CD-R. I chosed automatic partionning, and when I was asked where to put grub (with some message about the need of boot partition due to my disk or something like this) I chosed to put it on /dev/sda

Comment: @RACING121 photo uploaded

Comment: Did you attempt to enter **recovery mode (command-r)** when you had OS X? You could of reinstalled it.